# How to print in wince 6. R2?

Tags: windows-ce

msdn shows that OnPrint(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo) function is supported in wince 2.0 and above version but when i made the project then it showing that CPrintInof undecalare. i searched in msdn and found that for samrt device project CprintInfo can't be used

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6afzd4h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

So how to print in wince 6.0?is there any other way.

Answer (score 1):

We use the now fairly antiquated but probably still the best, [PrinterCE by FieldSoftware](http://www.fieldsoftware.com/PrinterCE.htm).  Can't vouch for their CE6 support but probably worth downloading the trial and having a go.